# Chrome Auto Selects IOS encoding but the Encoding I send is UTF-8 ? It works on FireFox and Internet Explorer

Tags: php, google-chrome, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

So Chrome won't display UTF-8 though my response is UTF-8 and the charset tag is also UTF-8 ?
it works on FireFox and IE. 
It only does that on two pages of the website 
I'm trying to force it into using UTF-8 but no luck.
the only way that actually worked so far is change the encoding in Chrome itself manually.
anyone have any idea why would this be happening and how to fix it ?
e.x :
FF and  IE would show :
Frédéric 
chrome shows
FrÃ©dÃ©ric 
?

Comment: Is this only for Chrome on iOS (per your title)? Do you have a sample URL we could look at? Also, are you able to set the charset header from the server?

Comment: not IOS device IOS-8859-1 encoding instead of UFT-8 and yes I set charset from server and it is set UTF-8 here is a url http://www.dossiya.com/example

Comment: for the exact example look at this page on all three you'll notice the difference http://stag2-dossiya.eu01.aws.af.cm/public/example

Comment: Can you add the exact code you're using to set the charset? Inspecting Chrome's developer tools network tab on that page, there's no Charset header in the server response (but it may be masked by your cache system).

Comment: The only soltuion that worked is making the server AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this was to add nothing surrounding it

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

I tried adding

AddCharset utf-8 .php but that didn't owrk

to the .htaccess file in the application it worked like a charm :)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged "php", you could try using:

`<?php   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>`